# "OpenIDs are in the form of URLs, not email addresses" - why do I see this and how can I avoid it?

Tags: support, bug, login

Occasionally when attempting to log into SO I get the error message "OpenIDs are in the form of URLs, not email addresses."

There's no discernible pattern to this and as far as I can ascertain it only occurs in IE (i.e. not in Firefox or Chrome)

My usual workaround here is to go to StackExchange site (this one) and log in there. When I go back to SO then I'm logged in. However that workaround didn't work this morning.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

If you use a password manager, it could be that - without you seeing this - the hidden login option for OpenId is filled by your password manager.

When I just received the message “OpenIDs are in the form of URLs, not email addresses”, I fixed it as follows:

- On the login screen I clicked on "More login options".
- This displayed in addition the text box for entering the OpenId. My password manager had entered my email address in the OperaId.
- I cleared the text in the OpenId box.
- Clicking on *Log In*, now worked.

BTW, I was using Chrome when this happened to me.

[image: OpenId hidden]

[image: OpenId now showing]

Comment: Thanks for this, will check this out the next time it occurs for me